# ENETUNREACH error on external calls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

In the past week, I started getting an unusual error while fetching external information (in this specific case, facebook):

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='graph.facebook.com',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.7/xxxxxx/xxxxx (Caused
>   by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 101] ENETUNREACH',))

I'm using the GCE load balancer and a few times per day I get the 502 no gateway error. There is only one instance (for now) behind the load balancer.

I'm tempted to believe I'm loosing internet connectivity on this instance for a short time (maybe a few seconds, the load balancer needs to make a few calls to flag it as working).

Anyone got issues with connectivity dropping on a compute engine instance? Anyone has an idea how to debug it?

Comment: I've been seeing unusual behavior over the past day on GKE with similar symptoms.    
  
    `WARNING:Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fcacdeae710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2]`

Comment: Are you using Nginx in the backend behind the HTTP Load Balancer?

Comment: Yes we are using nginx behind the load balancer. The 502 error comes from GCE though. It is clearly identified as such, so it's not nginx not being to reach our unix socket.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the following problem working with Nginx together with HTTP Load Balancer experiencing sporadic 502 bad gateway and you might find it helpful. Basically you I had to tune the server in order to make sure that the connection was not dropped by a timeout due to a race condition.

The main issue is that **"the default nginx keepalive_timeout is incompatible with the Google Cloud Platform HTTP(S) Load Balancer"**.

You must increase nginx’s 'keepalive_timeout', or risk intermittent and sporadic 502 Bad Gateway responses to POST requests.

```
# Tune nginx keepalives to work with the GCP HTTP(S) Load Balancer:
keepalive_timeout 650;
keepalive_requests 10000;
```

You can find an awesome article [here](https://blog.percy.io/tuning-nginx-behind-google-cloud-platform-http-s-load-balancer-305982ddb340) that helped me before, that shows the root cause of this problem.

EDIT. Sometimes I had issues also with the `NGINX Rate Limiting` [setting](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/) that was causing the HTTP health check to fail and to consider the instance unhealthy for a while, I don't know if it is related to your issue but it might be helpful for someone finding your question searching the 502 error.